# sampling rows with non-uniform inclusion probabilities in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sample, random

I have a matrix *M* with *n* rows, and I have an n-dimensional column vector *P* containing an inclusion probability for each row of *M*. Note that the probabilities may be different for every row and they do not add to one. I would like to efficiently sample the rows of *M*, by including each row *M_i* in the sample (independently) with probability *P_i*. Note that I do not need the sampled matrix to be of a specific size k, I just need for each row to be randomly selected according to its inclusion probability.

I have done quite a bit of searching and I am aware of *randsample* and *datasample*, but neither of these do quite what I am looking for. Is there a built-in function for this type of sampling? If not, what would be the most efficient way to accomplish this in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) compared against each probability to generate a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/) that tells which rows of `M` are picked.

The basic idea is that `rand` generates random numbers with uniform distribution in the interval (0,1), and thus the probability of one such number being less than a given *x* (with *x* between 0 and 1) is precisely *x*.

```
probs = [.6; .3; .2; .4]; %// contains n probabilities (where n is size(M,1))
ind = rand(size(probs))<probs; %// "0"/"1" logical index
result = M(ind,:) %// pick only rows with a "1"
```